# Google app script trigger not sending email

Tags: google-apps-script

Please can someone show me the error here (I think it will be very obvious for someone who has any knowledge of coding)? I have cobbled this script together from various sources but it does not work - the logic is correct as it works with the standard Google triggers (which i do not think I can use as I want to send email only in office hours Mon - Friday). Thanks in advance;

```
`enter code here`function startCustomTrigger()
{
ScriptApp.newTrigger('StartProcess').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
}

function StartProcess() {

var date = new Date(); 
var day = date.getDay(); 
var hrs = date.getHours(); 

if ((day >= 2) && (day <= 6) && (hrs >= 8) && (hrs <= 18)) {

// Get the sheet where the data is, in sheet 'Mail' 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mail") 
var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process since there is a header row 
var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process is set by a formula which 
counts rows 
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B6 where the emails and messages are 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
// Fetch values for each row in the Range to input into the mailing system 
var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
// This processes the emails you want to send 
for (i in data) { 
var row = data[i]; 
var emailAddress = row[0];   // First column is the email address 
var message = row[1]; // Second column is the message 
var subject = row[1]; // This is the subject of the email 
// This parses the data for the email to send 
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Read [mcve]. *Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.*

Comment: You have a typo: `counts rows`

Comment: @MariosKaramanis I think count rows is part of a comment

Answer (score 2):

You have these two declarations:

```
var message = row[1]; // Second column is the message 
var subject = row[1]; // This is the subject of the email
```

one must be incorrect

Try it this way:

```
function StartProcess(e) {
  var day = e['day-of-week'];//available from event object but a little different than that which comes from Date().getDay()
  var hrs = e.hour;//available from event object
  if ((day >= 1) && (day <= 5) && (hrs >= 8) && (hrs <= 18)) {
    const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    // Get the sheet where the data is, in sheet 'Mail' 
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Mail") 
    var startRow=2; // First row of data to process since there is a header row 
    var numRows=sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process is set by a formula which counts rows 
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B6 where the emails and messages are 
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2) 
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range to input into the mailing system 
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
    // This processes the emails you want to send 
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) { 
      var row = data[i]; 
      var emailAddress = row[0];   // First column is the email address 
      var message = row[1]; // Second column is the message 
      var subject = row[2]; // This is the subject of the email 
      // This parses the data for the email to send 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
    }
  }
}
```

[JavaScript getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

[timebased event objec](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

If you continue to have problems please provide an image of Mail Sheet.

Comment: I also think this should be the case.

Comment: Message and subject can be the same. Maybe it's just  a simple string: "Thank you!"

Comment: Hi, thanks but that returned the following error code:

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'day-of-week' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: message and subject are the same - v.simple message